# How to fix broken symbolic link in an M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, python, file, symlink

```
file /Users/gani/.local/pipx/venvs/aws-sso-util/bin/python
/Users/gani/.local/pipx/venvs/aws-sso-util/bin/python: broken symbolic link to python3.10
```

Here is more info:

```
ls /Users/gani/.local/pipx/venvs/aws-sso-util/bin/python
/Users/gani/.local/pipx/venvs/aws-sso-util/bin/python
```

```
which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

```
which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

which I try to recreate the symlink:

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /Users/gani/.local/pipx/venvs/aws-sso-util/bin/python
ln: /Users/gani/.local/pipx/venvs/aws-sso-util/bin/python: File exists
~/Documents/customer-control
```

How to fix the broken symbolic link?

Comment: Have you tried (re)creating the link with `ln -s <source> <destination>`?

Comment: yes, it failed. I have included the output in the question.

Comment: You have to delete the existing link first.

Comment: what is the command to do that?

Comment: `rm <filename>`. You can also use `ln -sf ….` that will “force”  the creation of the link overwriting the existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix a broken link is to simply recreate it.

```
ln -s <source> <target>
```

You need to remove the link first and you can do that with the command `rm <filename`. However, you can do this with in a single line with:

```
ln -sf <source> <target>
```

The `-f` flag “forces” the creation of the new link overwriting the existing file.